# Why Syntax Error: Unexpected Token T in JSON at position 0 while printing QWEb (PDF) in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, qweb

I'm using odoo 9, I've developed QWEB report, I tested on my local machine, it is working fine, But when I deployed it to server machine, I'm getting following error. Any one help?[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was memory issue, Actually there was some large calculations while printing report. So I just changed there and reduces calculation, and now my error has gone.